# JQuery doesn't register events on "refreshed" elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't really know how to explain this properly, but I'm learning how to use AJAX and while I've pretty much figured it out, I'm running into a problem with JQuery not referencing a call to a button that is regenerated at the end of a DIV. The reason this button is regenerated is because it's positioned inside of the div in which the content is being replaced. (In this case it's video cycling).

I've attatched a JSFiddle that shows my problem.

My javascript file is loaded at the bottom of my body, like so:

```
<html>
   <head>
       ...
   </head>

   <body>
      ...
      <script src="..."></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

```js
var i = 0;
$('#bar').on('click', function() {
  i++;
  $('#foo').html('<button id="bar">Test button: ' + i + '</button>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo">
  <button id="bar">Test button: 0</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are generating HTML dynamically with jQuery try Using **event delegation** :-

```
var i = 0;
$('#foo').on('click', '#bar' ,function() {
  i++;
  $('#foo').html('<button id="bar">Test button: ' + i + '</button>');
});
```

Or

```
var i = 0;
$(document.body).on('click', '#bar' ,function() {
  i++;
  $('#foo').html('<button id="bar">Test button: ' + i + '</button>');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6qnqd3b/)

Comment: the key here is to use the ON with something which is not dynamically created, for example body or #foo as you did, but to use a class or id in this case is not an issue

Comment: @AmrElGarhy..yes you are correct but in my opinion OP wants to generate new buttons inside div for which op should use `.append()` instead of `.html()` so in that case OP should use class instead of id's otherwise id's will get repeated.

Comment: @Kartikeya - Append doesn't do what I want, which is why I'm using `.html()` however a simple switch using your modifications has what I require working with `.html()` -- I still don't understand how using an id is improper, considering there's only ever one button.

Comment: @Kartikeya but I see in the question is using .html which means he want to replace the content

Comment: @AmrElGarhy - Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
var i = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.bar' ,function() {
   
  i = i+1;
  $('#foo').html('<button class="bar">Test button: ' + i + '</button>'); // instead of .html() use .append() here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <button id="bar" class="bar">Test button: 0</button>
</div>
```